# Unable to save frontend custom Post data

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I an building custom plugin so on meantime So on the meantime, I am stuck on frontend form, but currently, I am unable to post or save data to my database.
I have scoured the Google-verse and I have the die() function on the PHP callback and I believe the add_actions are correct.

I am working on a local host, though I doubt that affects it and this is all in the admin, not front end. I also checked that the js is enqueued and localised.

I get a 200 OK message in the chrome developer area.
Maybe someone can help me with a small problem I'm having. I'm trying to use below code to create a submit form for Wordpress post.

````
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying car archives, including the main car-data page which is a post type archive.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/car_data/archive-car-data.php
 *
 * @author      Shaikh Nadeem
 * @package     Car_Data
 * @subpackage  Car_Data/Templates
 * @version     1.0.0
 */

/**
 * 
 */
class Car_Frontend_Form
{

    function __construct()
    {
        add_shortcode( 'submit_car', array($this, 'submit_car') );

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'my_enqueue' ) );

        add_action( 'save_post_submit_car_data_post', array( $this, 'submit_car_data_post' ) );

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_car_data_post', array( $this, 'submit_car_data_post' ) );

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_submit_car_data_post', array( $this, 'submit_car_data_post' ) ); 

    }

    public function submit_car() {

        $html  = '<div id="submit_car_form">';
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>" />';
        $html .= '<form id="cd_car" name="cd_car" class="cd_car" method="post" action=" " >';
        $html .= '<p><label for="title">Title</label><br />';
        $html .= '<input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="40" name="title" />';
        $html .= '</p>';
        $html .= '<p>';
        $html .= '<label for="content">Post Content</label><br />';
        $html .= '<textarea id="content" tabindex="3" name="content" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>';
        $html .= '</p>';
        $html .= '<p>'. wp_dropdown_categories( "show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=feature" ) .'</p>';
        $html .= '<p><label for="post_tags">Tags</label>';
        $html .= ' <input type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" /></p>';
        $html .=  wp_nonce_field( "car-frontend-post" );
        $html .= '<p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit_car" name="submit_car" /></p>';
        $html .= '</form>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        return $html;
    }

    public function submit_car_data_post() {
        // check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_securiy_nonce', 'security' );
        if ( isset($_POST['title']) ) {
            $title     = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['post_title'] );
            $content   = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['content'] );
            $author_id = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['author_id'] );
            $tags_input = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['post_tags'] );
            $category = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cat'] );

            $args = array(
                'post_title'    => $title,
                'post_content'  => $content,
                'post_category' => $category,
                'tags_input'    => $tags_input,
                'author'        => $author_id,
                'post_status'   => 'draft',
                'post_type'     => 'car-data',
            );

            // Check that the nonce was set and valid
            if( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wpnonce'], 'car-frontend-post') ) {
                echo '<script>alert("Did not save because your form seemed to be invalid. Sorry");</scipt>';
                return;
            }

            if( is_wp_error( $posts ) ){
                echo json_encode( $posts->get_error_messages() );
                echo '<script>alert("is_wp_error!");</script>';
            } else {
                $post_preview = get_preview_post_link($posts);
                echo $post_preview;
                echo '<script>alert("'. $post_preview .'");</script>';
            }

            $posts = wp_insert_post( $args );
            echo '<script>alert("Saved your post successfully!");</script>';
            echo $posts;
            wp_die();            
        }
    } 


    public function my_enqueue() {

        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    }


}

```
Also i have custom post type to save on the same form but till here i not aed that field
````

Comment: edit your question to show us the javascript code you use to make the AJAX call.

Comment: You are not ever doing the `save_post_submit_car_data_post` action. Perhaps you need to check in the `submit_car` function if it is a POST request and then do this action or else show the form.

Comment: tll now i m not use javascript code @Kaperto

Comment: @GeorgeQ can you please help me  how to solve this issue